# The intersection of two or more open neighborhood deformation retracts onto the maximal tree.

Tags: algebraic-topology

At Hatcher Page 43, there's a statement next to this picture says

> The intersection of two or more $A_\alpha's$ deformation retracts onto $T$.

Here $T$ is the maximal tree of the graph $X$ shown in the figure. $A_\alpha$ is defined to be

> Choose for each edge $e_\alpha$ of $X-T$ an open neighborhood $A_\alpha$ of $T \cup e_\alpha$ in $X$ that deformation retracts onto $T \cap e_\alpha$.

So my question is, if two $A_\alpha$s are chosen as below, then their intersection is empty, can I still say that their intersection deformation retracts onto $T$ since it vacuously true?

It is otherwise true, since as long as their intersection is not empty, their intersection is simply connected with $T$,  since deformation retracts onto $T$.

[image]

Comment: Something's not right here.  Your green set, for example, looks like it is supposed to be a suitable $A_\alpha$ for the obvious edge $e_\alpha$.  But the green set is not a neighborhood of $T \cup e_\alpha$; the green set does not contain $T$.  Maybe you should say $T \cap e_\alpha$ instead of $T \cup e_\alpha$?

Answer (score 0):

No, the empty subspace cannot be a deformation retract of any nonempty space $S$.  A deformation retraction needs a homotopy $F$ for which (among other conditions) $F(s, 1)$ is in the subspace, but since there is at least one $s \in S$ and the subspace is empty, this is impossible.

Comment: Thank you, I added he original document. :-)